# Visual Studio 2013 crash when open a nodejs project

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, codeplex

I developed a project in nodejs on Visual Studio 2013 full edition with Nodejs plugin of Codeplex (http://nodejstools.codeplex.com/).

It always worked fine till, one week ago, when I decided to upgrade (as suggested) the Nodejs pluging. Now Visual Studio crash every time I open a project in nodejs and print me this alert:

[image: VS2013 has stopped working]

No problem with other type of projects.

My PC has a quad core i7 CPU, 16GB ram and the SO is Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this.

Node.js tools plugin on VIsual Studio suggested me to update it to the lastest beta version.
I innocently accepted and then started my problem.

I has been necessary to remove the plugin and install the suggested one from http://nodejstools.codeplex.com/ to solve the problem.

You cannot uninstall it from the extension view of VS (tools->Extensions and updates) 'cause it a SO application, therefore it must be removed from Control Panel->uninstall programs.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks. VS.NET was hanging when loading a Node project.
Installed "NTVS Dev 2014-07-03 VS 2013.msi"